# How can I get this vaue from XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML :

```
<meteo_italia>
    <localita>
        <id>2861</id>
        <nome>Foppolo</nome>
        <prov>BG</prov>
        <capoluogo>0</capoluogo>
        <regione>LOMBARDIA</regione>
        <previsione time="2011-10-28T06:00">
            <id_tempo>6</id_tempo>
            <desc_tempo>temporali isolati</desc_tempo>
            <temp>2</temp>
            <press>1024.3</press>
            <um_rel>78</um_rel>
            <zerot>3000 m</zerot>
            <qn>ND</qn>
            <v_dir>ESE</v_dir>
            <v_int>4 nodi</v_int>
            <ore_s>3</ore_s>
            <prec>0-10mm</prec>
        </previsione>
        <previsione time="2011-10-28T12:00">
            <id_tempo>6</id_tempo>
            <desc_tempo>temporali isolati</desc_tempo>
            <temp>11</temp>
            <press>1024.9</press>
            <um_rel>46</um_rel>
            <zerot>3550 m</zerot>
            <qn>ND</qn>
            <v_dir>SSO</v_dir>
            <v_int>3 nodi</v_int>
            <ore_s>3</ore_s>
            <prec>0-10mm</prec>
        </previsione>

        ... XML continues...
```

and I'd like to extract the value `temp` from the second node `previsione` on C#.

Tried with :

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    m_strFilePath = wc.DownloadString(xmlMeteo);
}

XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.LoadXml(m_strFilePath);

try
{
    Response.Write("Value : " + myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//previsione[position()=0]//temp").Value);
}
catch { }
```

but I can't get it.

Comment: also valid,//previsione[position()=2]/temp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your query to:

```
"//previsione[2]/temp"
```

and access `.InnerText` rather than `.Value` ([since `.Value` rarely has an actual value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx), and never for elements).

the `[2]` should (as requested) fetch the *second* item; the `/temp` means "child element named temp".

Comment: Yeah it seems to work! Which language I'm used to query this value? This is not XPath...

Comment: @markzzz yes it is; 1.0 spec, section 2.5; abbreviated syntax; direct link: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your XPath string is wrong - double slash ("//") when used where you've got it is to get a descendant (http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathdescendant.php).

Try just using a single slash as that will just get the child.

```
//previsione[2]/temp
```

Also - XSLT elements are not zero-based, so elements start at pos = 1

Here is a website I find is great for getting xPath strings It also formats XML great too! !

http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/index.html

Comment: See edit - sorry I missed read the part saying you wanted the 2nd element! 

Thanks to @Marc Gravell for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

The node postion of XPath is basing on 1, not 0. please try:

```
myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//previsione[2]/temp/text()").Value;
```